# How to make a looped corner (like in FontLab) in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point, fontlab-studio

There's a feature in FontLab that allows you to turn a corner into "**Looped corner**":

[image]

I'm looking for a way to do that in Illustrator. What I do now, is to add an anchor point besides an existing corner. Then, I extend both anchor points in the path direction to create a loop. This method doesn't perform well when there are handles in either side of anchor.

[image]

Another method I use is to break the anchor using Scissors, then switch to Extend Path tool (Part of VectorScribe) and extend both sides and join them:

[image]

I think there must be a better and shorter way for doing that like a script or plugin.

Comment: Hi. Usually loops like this are something to be avoided. Can I ask why you need it?

Comment: I dont think there is a script for this. Its a very niche need. But also the scripting layer is really low level and does not expose stuff very much., So you cant extend lines or add point sin middle of a curve. You have to rebuild entire shapes but tahts slow indeed.

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi, loops are very useful when you're editing a corner. Many times it happens that I want to move just one side of the corner. If there's a loop there, then the other side won't move. (I remove all these overlaps in my final designs)

Comment: @joojaa Well, it's kind of disappointing if it can't be done even using scripts. Maybe I should better ask Astute team to work on it.

Comment: @MahmoudArasteh if you cut at the corner you get the same thing just move along opposite curve. You can merge the shape with effect booleans on groups. i didnt say it cant be done just very tedious and slow. But then you dont need it...